# Eclipse maven launch "has encoutered a problem" No selected resource

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Developing a Maven project in Eclipse, when I click the launch button, the launch will often fail with the error:

> 'Launching *project_name*' has encountered a problem.
>   No selected resource

This is because I have not selected a Java class file in the editor before clicking the Launch button (little green play icon).

Usually, I have the maven console, or Git staging view in focus at the time I press the button, so I understand why it is happening, just not how to prevent it.

Surely the play button knows which project to select. Why should it care which view has focus when I press the button? The launch configuration refers to the project via a value like `${project_loc:project_name}` in the *Base directory* field.

**Is there a way I can tell Eclipse to just run the maven build, regardless of what focus the IDE has?**

I am running Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0) on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ***Window > Preferences: Run/Debug > Launching*** choose ***Always launch the previously launched application*** as *Launch Operation*.

Make also sure **not** to **use selection based variables** like `${git_branch}` without an argument.

To make `git_branch` independent of the selection, specify the resource (file or folder) from which you want to have the current branch name. For example, `${git_branch:/my_project}`.

Comment: Thanks @howlger. I had in fact tried that already, and tested it again now.
However, it doesn't seem to work for me with the maven console in focus.

Comment: @NetWolf So your issue is not that the wrong launch configuration is run, but that the execution of the correct launch configuration is not possible due to the error, right? Do you use any variables other than `${project_loc:project_name}`  in the Maven launch configuration?

Comment: Yes. Correct. I do pass in `-DgitBranch=${git_branch}`

Comment: I see. I have expanded my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @howlger. Specifying the directory name in the `${git_branch}` has fixed it.